# OSX - ignore_match - SublimeLinter - HTML-tidy

Tags: html, macos, sublimetext, htmltidy, linter

I'm trying to get **SublimeLinter** and **HTML-tidy** ignore specific errors on my html file. I never used **SublimeLinter** before so I'm kinda confused.

Is there any way I can ignore unnecessary errors? because it's kinda annoying to see a lot of orange mark on my screen.

[Here's my HTML Interface (lot's of errors)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcNEH.png)

I keep getting `warning: link inserting "type" attribute`  and a lot more.

[And here's my SublimeLinter.sublime-settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpyAs.png)

I tried these settings:

```
"htmllint": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": [],
                "ignore_match": {
                    "inc": [
                        "missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration",
                        "inserting implicit <body>",
                        "inserting missing 'title' element",
                        "<link> inserting 'type' attribute"
                    ]
                }

            },
```

and

```
"htmltidy": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "excludes": [],
                "ignore_match": {
                    "inc": [
                        "missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration",
                        "inserting implicit <body>",
                        "inserting missing 'title' element",
                        "<link> inserting 'type' attribute"
                    ]
                }
            },
```

but nothing seems to work.

Comment: according to [this document](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/linter_settings.html#ignore-match), you are telling the linter to only ignore those matches on files with an `.inc` extension. Try removing the `{ "inc":` bit (and the corresponding `}` character) so that it will apply to all files.